# loop through all methods in a python program

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x

I want to do something like this:

```
def a():
  # do stuff
  return stuff

def b():
  # do stuff
  return different_stuff

def c():
  # do one last thing
  return 200

for func in this_file:
  print func_name
  print func_return_value
```

I essentially want to mimic this flask app, without the flask parts:

```
app = Flask(__name__)
app.register_blueprint(my_bp, url_prefix='/test')
my_bp.data = fake_data

def tests():
  with app.test_client() as c:
    for rule in app.url_map.iter_rules():
      if len(rule.arguments) == 0 and 'GET' in rule.methods:
        resp = c.get(rule.rule)
        log.debug(resp)
        log.debug(resp.data)
```

is this possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Like this:

```
import sys

# some functions...
def a():
   return 'a'

def b():
   return 'b'

def c():
   return 'c'

# get the module object for this file    
module = sys.modules[__name__]

# get a list of the names that are in this module  
for name in dir(module):
   # get the Python object from this module with the given name
   obj = getattr(module, name)
   # ...and if it's callable (a function), call it.
   if callable(obj):
      print obj()
```

running this gives:

```
bgporter@varese ~/temp:python moduleTest.py
a
b
c
```

Note that the functions will not necessarily be called in the order of definition as they are here.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe:

```
def a(): return 1
def b(): return 2
def c(): return 3

for f in globals ().values ():
    if callable (f): continue
    print f.__name__
    print f ()
```

Comment: use `callable(f)` to determine if `f` can be called. cf. http://docs.python.org/2.7/library/functions.html#callable

Answer (score 1):

Use this code to create the python module get_module_attrs.py

```
import sys
module = __import__(sys.argv[1])
for name in dir(module):
   obj = getattr(module, name)
   if callable(obj):
      print obj.__name__
```

Then you can call it as `$python get_module_attrs.py <name_of_module>`

Enjoy it!!